# An align environment error

Tags: align

I have an issue to run the following code in an align environment:

```
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{D}^{(m)} = \mathbf{D} \mathbf{D} \cdots \mathbf{D} =  \mathbf{D}^m,\quad \boldsymbol{f}^{(m)} = \mathbf{D}^{(m)} \boldsymbol{f}
\end{align}
```

The error message shows me the following:
"Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte 168. fractional advection� "

Where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: There is a possibility that a non-printing unicode character slipped into your input.  If you have narrowed it down to this block of code, consider retyping the equation in from scratch.  FYI, when I copy and paste this code into a document, it works just fine.

Comment: A separate question: Why do you use an `align` environment, which is meant to be used for multi-line displayed equations, for what appears to be a single line of displayed math? Put differently, why don't you use an `equation` environment?

Comment: I don't think that the equation you show is responsible for the error, which instead refers to some text part, after an appearance of the word *advection*.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Thank you for your help! The problem was solved when I added this statement (\UserawInputEncoding) at the beginning of the article.

Comment: @egreg Maybe it is. I'm missing one statement.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. That's a good idea！